TRUNCATE ui_bookmark; will delete all users?
I get the errors while customers add.
err: Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state
solution: TRUNCATE ui_bookmark; ? is the right solutions?
it'll be delete all users or only null values.
i've several users. if I mess, it's totally makes huge headache..

The UI Bookmark mainly stores User-Specific Configurations, Saves States or sessions, Bookmarks or favorite items, custom filters, or searches.
When you truncate data from this ui_bookmark table it restores the default settings.
As you are concerned about your users, you can safely truncate the table using the criteria below.

Identify your namespace (there is a column namespace in ui_bookmark, for  eg. customer_listing)

Identify the user in the field user_id

Now you have a namespace and user_id, add a condition in your delete query so that it deletes data for the user for which you are facing the issue.


For example,
DELETE FROM ui_bookmark WHERE namespace = 'customer_listing' AND user_id = 2;

Thanks!

The ui_bookmark table stores the filter you apply in admin for entities such as product,customer etc admin user wise..
you can fire a sql to delete for specific admin user..the sql would be
DELETE FROM ui_bookmark WHERE user_id = 1;
//Assuming you want to delete it for user with id =1....
you can find user id for your user in table admin_user and column user_id..
Hope it helps..do let me know if any other help needed
